# Huge text generated using raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I wanted to draw text at the **center** of polygon and **into** the polygon formed by path value. I tried using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kitex/Djy4s/1/) fiddle but the text is drawn on paper not polygon.

```
 //for writing text
        var bbox = obj.getBBox();
        var x = Math.floor(bbox.x + bbox.width/2.0); 
        var y = Math.floor(bbox.y + bbox.height/2.0);
        alert(x + " and " + y);
        r.text(x, y, "t");
```

Actually I wanted to write text at the **center** and **into** polygon like a label! Like country name at the center of polygon that's all!

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @ErikDahlström sorry you didn't understand the question I have edited it hope you will understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your question really was "why is the text so huge?", and perhaps "why is it misplaced?". Something like this perhaps:

http://jsfiddle.net/nhYSr/

I'd recommend avoiding such a small viewBox, because browsers tend to have issues with very small (smaller than 1px) font-sizes.

Comment: can't the text be fitting into the polygon area?

Comment: How do I make viewBox larger or any other solution?

Comment: SVG doesn't do automatic layout, but you already know the polygon area when you author the svg, so just place the text where you want and it will stay there. To change the viewBox it's probably easiest to use a vector graphics editor, set a new viewBox and scale up the paths until they fit the new viewBox. Or you can use http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.transformPath.